# Activecampaign API - add multiple users to a list at once?

Tags: php, api

I am just starting out with the activecampaign / php API.
I need to add multiple users to a list, and 
I was wondering if there is a way to add an array of users instead a single user.

According to
https://www.activecampaign.com/api/example.php?call=contact_add
I can update a list with 1 user per API call.

```
$contact = array(
    "email"              => "test@example.com",
    "first_name"         => "Test",
    "last_name"          => "Test",
    "p[{$list_id}]"      => $list_id,
    "status[{$list_id}]" => 1, // "Active" status
);

$contact_sync = $ac->api("contact/sync", $contact);
```

Looping this does not seem optimal - it would seem much better if I could simply pass an array of users when I connect to the API.

Any help or hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a limitation of the API. You'd need to reach out to them with a feature request or just make one API call per contact.

Comment: A very belated thank you for your response =)

Answer (score 3):

There is not currently a way to bulk add contacts to lists.

Also, the endpoint you listed ([*contact_add*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr1Re.png)) is for creating a new contact, which is great if you want to create a contact and add the contact to a list all at the same time. To add an existing contact to a list, you should use [*contact_sync*](https://www.activecampaign.com/api/example.php?call=contact_sync).

You can submit requests for new endpoints and functionality through ActiveCampaign's [website](https://www.activecampaign.com/login/?section=ideas) (must log into account to do so).

Comment: Thank you, I might try contacting them =)

Comment: This is for API version 1. API version 3, does not have a batch contact sync feature. Mailchimp and Klaviyo do.